# ¿Como centrar mapa cuando Div cambia de tamaño?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

Como hago para mantener centrado el mapa cada vez que cambie la clase del elemento `MyMap`, lo cual esta especificado en los estilos css.

```
    $scope.eldiv = document.getElementById('MyMap'); 
    var boxOne = document.getElementsByClassName('map')[0],
        btnone = document.getElementsByClassName('absolute')[0],
        lalista = document.getElementsByClassName('lista')[0],  
        map      


      document.getElementsByClassName('absolute')[0].onclick = function () {
        if (!lalista.classList.contains('mapCambia')) {
            boxOne.classList.toggle('mapCambia');
            btnone.classList.toggle('botonlista');
            lalista.classList.toggle('listaCambia');
            });

        }
    };

    function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map($scope.eldiv, mapOptions);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Estilos css

```
.absolute {
position: relative;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
width: 40px;
z-index: 99;
bottom: 25px;
transition: 2s;
}

.lista {
height: 0%;
width: 100%;
z-index: 98;
transition: 2s;
}

.lista.listaCambia {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
z-index: 98;
}
.absolute.botonlista {
position: relative;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
width: 40px;
}
```

Comment: No has tratado de usar Flex-Box?

Comment: no tengo de ese conocimiento, si me puedes facilitar, te agradezco

Comment: Claro, echale un vistazo esto, ya lo busco en español [link flex-box](http://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí hay varios metodos de alinear verticalmente elementos http://vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/ Creo que el que mejor te convendria seria el de las tablas

```css
#parent {display: table;}

#child {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Content here</div>
</div>
```